# How to place menu items in middle?

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem

I want to center the menu items. Currently, the menu items are on the left

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul#menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
}
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
}
ul#menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
}
ul#menu li a:active {
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

I now have this:
[menu left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmCf0.png)

I want this:
[menu middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcD6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your item stays left is because you have a `float: left;` on each li(menu items).

#### Solution 1: use flexbox with the following in your parent(container):

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
```

You need `flex-wrap: wrap;` because by default flexbox set it to `nowrap` which is not mobile responsive when you have a small screen size.

```css
ul#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul#menu li {
  float: left;
}

ul#menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #222222;
}

ul#menu li a:active {
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### Solution 2: use `text-align: center;` on parent container then `display: inline-block;` on child, remove the `float: left`:

```
ul#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
ul#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #222222;
}

ul#menu li a:active {
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```